# Display Size Change event in Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, onconfigurationchanged

I was just checking with nougat settings on my Nexus 5x and found a setting as **Display Size**.
I added: **`android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|density"`** for my activity in Manifest file so that I should get the event for Display Size change in **`onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`** method in my activity.

But when I change Display Size from settings, my activity restarts and I don't even get a callback in **`onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`**.
I tried adding a log, but that even isn't shown.

In Manifest file;

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/home"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|density"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

In my activity,

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.e("test","executed");
    // My code here..
}
```

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: try adding : android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: Tried. Not worked.

Comment: can you please post some code here?

Comment: @TrickySolutions : I have edited the question.  Please check. Though adding code doesn't make any change, the question is quite simple.

Comment: try removing ** android:screenOrientation="portrait" ** and check it now

Comment: @TrickySolutions, doesn't work bro :(

Comment: i had the same question. cool